# How to pass through data from a child form into the parent form without refreshing the list

Tags: c#, list

I am doing a school project in creating a POS system and i need to pass in through the same order list throughout the different form.The problem is everytime i return to the main menu, the list refreshes although i still need the data is there anyway to prevent this from happening?

```
    public partial class Main : Form
{

    List<string> order = new List<string>();
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public Main(List<string> order)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.order = order;

    }
```

this is the start code for the main menu

And this is the code to add the items from thelistbox to the list

```
 private void confirmbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        order.AddRange(temp_order);
        if (pendinglist.Items.Count != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your Items have been added! yay!", "That Sushi", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No items was selected.", "That Sushi", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        pendinglist.Items.Clear();

    }
```

Thank you in advance for your help.Please let me know if anything else is wrong with the code too. again thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You are probably closing the form and re-creating it every time you open it again, and since these orders are inside it, obviously the previous content is lost.

**Solution** : that list of orders should be outside main form

Here's a really simple pattern for you, it's really primitive but it works and should be enough/plausible for your homework : a static class

```
public static class MyModel
{
    public static Order Order { get; set; }

    public static void NewOrder()
    {
        Order = new Order();
    }
}

public class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        Products = new List<Product>();
    }

    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public void AddProduct(Product product)
    {
        Products.Add(product);
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

And here's how you'd use it from a form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonNewOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyModel.NewOrder();
    }

    private void buttonAddProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var product = new Product();
        product.Name = "PS4";
        product.Price = 1000000000.0m;

        MyModel.Order.AddProduct(product);
    }

    private void buttonShowProductsInOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var order = MyModel.Order;
        var products = order.Products;
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var product in products)
        {
            var format = string.Format("Name: {0}, Price: {1}", product.Name, product.Price);
            builder.AppendLine(format);
        }
        MessageBox.Show(builder.ToString());
    }
}
```

Order will not vanish and will be accessible from many forms.

Obviously it's a pretty bad practice, gurus would use MVP (model view presenter), MVC (model view controller) or whatever pattern along a database behind, but there's little point to roll out such design for your question. You can/should take a look at what these concepts are, however.

Good luck !

Comment: Thank you so much this helped me alot. Thx again!!